# Display json data in a table

Tags: angularjs, json

I have added `json` data inside controller directly and I need to display it in a table.

```
 var app = angular
                    .module("myApp", [])
                    .controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
                    var userList=[
                    {
                        "name":"John",
                        "age":"22",
                        "dept":"admin"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"Riya",
                        "age":"21",
                        "dept":"Java"
                    }
                    ];
                    });
```

How to do it?

Sample code: https://jsfiddle.net/ots8saak/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change var to $scope,

```
 var userList= [...];
```

to

```
$scope.userList = [...];
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gymbh2ah/)**